# Run as constrained user in Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, runas

I need to run my program.exe as **constrained** user in Windows.

I know about `runas /trustlevel:10000 "program.exe"`, but unfortunately my program needs to read from one particular file and write to another, also it would be good to redirect input and output to files. Here there is a problem - once program.exe started under constrained user *(10000)*, it has no rights to open any file.

I think possible solution is to create new user with `net user ... /ADD` command, with constrained rights, and then allow this user to modify file, in file security settings. Can you help me? I can't find out how to create such constrained user, it seems possible to create only normal user or admin. And it is needed to do all this stuff from cmd.

Thank you very much!

Comment: `icacls filename.ext /grant *S-1-5-12:F`

Comment: Thanks! You've made my day.

Answer (score 0):

If you open process explorer,you will find the restrict process is in this group NT AUTHORITY\RESTRICTED:
[image]

And according to [this](https://github.com/fishilico/shared/blob/master/windows/well_known_sids.c#L202)

The sid of RESTRICTED group is S-1-5-12,so you can use the command bellow to add the permission for a folder:

```
icacls "C:\Programs" /grant "*S-1-5-12:(OI)(CI)(RX)"
```